# Spring Boot Isolation.SERIALIZABLE not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2, isolation-level

I need help with this scenario, in theory the isolation level of `Serializable` should stop delete from happening, but in this scenario it still deletes the row with id 1, I have tried `@EnableTransactionManagement` and isolation repeatable read, it still doesn't block the delete nor cause the delete to throw exception

In summary, I need to stop any delete invocation whenever the update method is still ongoing

I am using `H2` in memory database for this sample

Thanks

Entity:

```
public class Something {

  @Id
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  private String desc;
}
```

Repo:

```
public interface SomeRepository extends JpaRepository<Something, Integer> {
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class SomeService {

  @Autowired
  private SomeRepository someRepository;

  public void deleteSomething2(Something something) {

    try {
      Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    someRepository.delete(something);
  }

  @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
  public void updateSomething2(Something something) {
    Something something1 = someRepository.findById(1).get();

    try {
      Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    something1.setName("namanama");
    someRepository.saveAndFlush(something1);
  }
```

Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService service;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    futures.add(executorService.submit(() -> service.updateSomething2(Something.builder().id(1).name("namaone").build())));
    futures.add(executorService.submit(() -> service.deleteSomething2(Something.builder().id(1).build())));  
    while(futures.stream().filter(f -> f.isDone() == false).count() > 0) {
      Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
        List<Something> all = service.findAll();
        System.out.println(all);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use the @Transactional in the test method to apply the transactional support in the test.

Comment: doesn't work, still deleting unfortunately

Comment: I am having the same problem. Could you solve it?